# How Can I add My Captured Image to My Hashmap

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I am still learning hashmaps and database structures so please forgive me if this is a basic question. I've tried to research but nothing seems to work. I have a method in the same activity where I capture an image which is pushed to Firebase Storage. The image successfully goes to Firebase Storage, but I cannot figure out how to add the image to my hashmap to go to the Firebase Database. My hashmap is below and currently works.
Thank you for your help.

```
    String title = title_edit_text.getText().toString();
    String first_name = firstname.getText().toString();
    String last_name = lastname.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
        title_edit_text.setError("Input is required!");
    } else {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date date = new Date();
        String creation_date= dateFormat.format(date);
       
        DateFormat date_format_for_time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        Date time = new Date();
        String creation_time= date_format_for_time.format(time);

        HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
        userMap.put("title", title);
        userMap.put("creation_date", creation_date); 
        userMap.put("creation_time", creation_time); 
        userMap.put("first_name", first_name);
        userMap.put("last_name", last_name);

        String upload = UsersReference2.push().getKey();
        UsersReference2.child(upload).setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    sendBackActivity();
                    Toast.makeText(Adding_Activity.this, "Successfully Save.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                    Toast.makeText(AddingActivity.this, "Error. Did Not Save: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == Gallery_Pick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        image_uri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity(image_uri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(3, 2)
                .start(this);
    }

    // when pressing the crop button//
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            StorageReference filePath = CoverPostReference.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(Adding_Activity.this, "Image has been added sucessfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Task<Uri> result = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();

                        result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                                UsersReference2.child("cover_image").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(Adding_Activity.this, "Image has been stored...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                } else {
                                                    String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                    Toast.makeText(Adding_Activity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Adding_Activity.this, "Error: Image did not upload. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: "how to add the image to my hashmap" I'm not sure what this means. Can you show what is currently being stored in the database, and what you want it to store instead?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your response. I have updated my code with the method that sends the image to storage. I am trying to figure out how to not only send to storage, but to also add the image uri or string (im not quite sure) to my hashmap. So when i look at the real time database i see the path to my image along with my hasmap (if that makes sense).  like for example: userMap.put ("myImage", image) - however that does not work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for that, that helps a lot. I see that you write the download URL to the database with `UsersReference2.child("cover_image")`, but you write the map with `UsersReference2.child(upload).setValue(userMap)`. Is the URL not showing up in the database? Or is it showing up in the database, but in the wrong place?

Comment: Ahhh sorry that wasnt clear. Its going to the database but to the wrong node.

Comment: I added a link to an image which shows the database structure im trying to achieve in the firebase database.

Comment: You will need to somehow make the value of `upload` available to the code in `onActivityResult`. Once you do that, you can set the image URL with `UsersReference2.child(upload).child("cover_image").setValue(downloadUrl)`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't/wouldn't store the image bitmap data into the hashmap, instead you should store the location to the bitmap (URI) to the hashmap (and database) and then use that to access the image.

Storing

```
Map<String, Uri> bitmapUriMap = new HashMap<String,Uri>();
bitmapUriMap.put("MyLocalBitmapName", UriOfBitmap);
```

Accessing

Then when you have the URI you just decode it

```
Uri uri = bitmapUriMap.get("MyLocalBitmapName);
Bitmap decodedUri = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(uri.getPath()));
```

This is what you would store in the database. For instance if you want the image of a user, then you would store the image uri within your firebase database and then you would access it this way. Storing a bitmap in a database is not ideal and not recommended.